# Generate t distribution density plot with pre-specified mean

Tags: r, distribution

I would like to create a Student's t distribution density plot with a mean of 0.02 instead of 0. is that possible to do?

the distribtion should have 2 degrees of freedom.

is this possible to do?

I tried the following:

```
X<-rnorm(100000,mean=0.02, sd=(1/sqrt(878)))
pop.mean<-mean(X)
t<-sapply(1:10000, function(x) (mean(sample(X,100))-pop.mean)/(1/sqrt(878)))

plot(density(t))
```

1. Is this approach correct?
2. If it is correct, how can I get the real densities, not just the approximation?

Comment: Use `dt` and its non-centrality parameter?

Comment: ok, in that case, what do I use for values of X? and how does the ncp correspond to the mean of 0.02?

Comment: looks like you actually want `rt`, since you are simulating?

Comment: I'm only simulating because I don't know how to draw the true densities. it would prefer using dt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement and example contradict each other somewhat.

Do you want a non-central t distribution which is based on a normal with mean 0.02?  This is what your example suggests, but note that the non-central t is not just a shifted t, it is now skewed.

If you want the non-central t then you can plot it with a command like:

```
 curve(dt(x,2,0.02), from=-5, to=6)
```

Or, do you want a shifted t distribution? A distribution that is symmetric around 0.02 with the shape of a t distribution?

You can plot the curve shifted by using a command like:

```
curve(dt(x-0.02,2), from=-5, to=6 )
```

The `curve` function has an `add` argument that you could use to plot both on the same plot if you want to compare them (not much difference in this case), changing the color on one of them would be suggested.

Comment: I want the second one. however your code produces a density centered around 0 and not 0.02

Comment: @user3742038, try the code again but with a number further away form 0 and you will see that the plotted density is centered at the value subtracted, not 0.

Comment: @GregSnow My big problem is not to plot a shifted t distributin but to genreate from shifted t distribution  How to do that? if some wants the following x~f(x-delta) wehre delta =2 how to do? i used this:x<-rt(10,3)+2 but i think it is falsse sine we do use non centrality parametr in that case  but how to express that shifting delta through ncp?

Comment: @ZB, a shifted t distribution and a non-central t distribution are different things.  If you want to generate data from the non-central t, then use the ncp parameter in the `rt` function.  If you want to generate from a shifted t, then use the code in your comment.

Comment: @GregSnow Nope.That is the problem that thousand of people do not know or understand .When we want to test the alternative : delta is different from 0, we use the ncp and by the way y<-rt(10,3)+delta is totally false and even absude since rt is only defined in R plus.

Comment: @ZB, for testing you are correct that the non-centrality parameter is the correct approach.  But there are reasons for generating data other than testing, and some of these may want to generate data from a distribution with the properties of the central t, but centered at a value other than 0.

Comment: @GregSnow Now can you help me ? i want to test for shift =2 .how to express that with non central t-distribution?

Comment: @ZB, I am not sure what exactly you are asking.  Maybe you should start a new question where you can give details rather than commenting on a  6 year old answer.